# Translation of Plus and Minus button previous and next to EditText Respectively Code that is in Kotlin to Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello i am having an Edit text that has a minus and plus button next to and after the Edit text. The edit text will have an input option for inputting a number then the minus button will decrease the value of the entered number in the edit text upon being pressed and the plus button will increase the value of the entered number in the edit text upon being pressed. The issue am having is that am following a tutorial and the code in the Main activity that has the on Click listeners for the button is in Kotlin and am well familiar with java compared to Kotlin, i would appreciate a nice translation of the code in Main Activity from Kotlin to android java

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrease"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/integer_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The following code below is the one which is in Kotlin and i would appreciate if it is in android Java form

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        increase.setOnClickListener { increaseInteger() }
        decrease.setOnClickListener { decreaseInteger() }
    }

    fun increaseInteger() {
        display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
    }

    fun decreaseInteger() {
        display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
    }

    private fun display(number: Int) {
        integer_number.setText("$number")
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the following link about [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "Questions must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your code in Java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.increase).setOnClickListener(this)
        findViewById(R.id.decrease).setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    public void increaseInteger() {
        display(Integer.parseInt(integer_number.getText().toString()) + 1);
    }

    public void decreaseInteger() {
        display(Integer.parseInt(integer_number.getText().toString()) - 1);
    }

    private fun display(int number) {
        integer_number.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.increase:
            increaseInteger()
            break;

            case R.id.decrease:
            decreaseInteger()
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I did it in notepad. So if you have any problem, let me know.

Comment: to answer questions like these doesn't really help the community, as OP has to show some sort of effort in trying to solve this for themselves. as a side note, you might have to re-look `integer_number.setText(...`  and any other references to `integer_number` :)

Comment: I have edited the question to further explain my self further, i have never learnt Kotlin

Comment: @a_local_nobody helping someone is anyway is good. One might have urgent requirement for this that's why asked this question.